# In PHP is it possible to explode 3 dimensionally?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

for example:

```
$sting = 'house : 3 bedroom, car : porsche 911 wife : model';
```

explode by : for rows and , for columns to form an array thusly

```
array(

    "house" => "3 bedroom"

    "car" => "porsche 911"

    "wife" => "model"

)
```

Without have to explode the foreach explode.

Comment: Living the good life there !

Comment: I would simply use a foreach loop, because this is the easiest way and creates the best readable code. All alternative commands you could use make this task unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `foreach` you can use a callback on `array_map` or `array_walk` but that is still iterating the array. Why not just use foreach?

You have to use explode twice to achieve this. First to separate the entires, then to divide the entires into key and value:

```
$string = 'house : 10 bedroom, car : porsche 911, wife : model';
$elements = explode(',', $string);
array_walk($elements, 'trim');

$goodLife = array();

foreach($elements as $element) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $element, 2);
    $goodLife[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}

print_r($goodLife);
```

**Functions used:**

- [explode()](http://php.net/explode)
- [array_walk()](http://php.net/array-walk)
- [trim()](http://php.net/trim)
- [list()](http://php.net/list)

Comment: The question was **without** using a foreach loop.

Comment: @Armin I missed that. There is no way to do it without iteration of some kind. Whether it's a `foreach` or a callback on `array_reduce()`, `array_walk()`, or `array_map()`, you'll need iteration.

Comment: The problem was having to do a nested foreach but you seam to have have don it in one. Thanks that looks like it would do it.

Comment: I bet you can make that simpler +

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array_reduce(
    explode(',', $sting /*[sic!] ;)*/),
    function ($array, $item) {
        list ($key, $value) = explode(':', $item, 2);
        $array[trim($key)] = trim($value);
        return $array;
    },
    array()
);
```

[`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array-reduce)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot come up with anything smarter than this:

```
$s = 'house : 3 bedroom, car : porsche 911 wife : model';
$a = preg_split("/[:,]/", $s);
$b = array();
array_unshift($a, false);
while (false !== $key = next($a)) {
  $b[$key] = next($a);
}
```

Comment: `next()` returns `false`, if the pointer reches the end, anyway, so what is the extra `false` good for? (`while(($key = next($a)) && ($value = next($a))) { $b[$key] = $value; }`)

Answer (score 0):

without foreach, i don't think they provide such a method.

Comment: Hmm, it should. I will have to make my own fro now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible, without using a foreach loop - because there is no command existing in PHP where you can split a string to array key and value.

Comment: I remember once I used a function that converted exploded arrays into

$house = "3 bedroom";

I cant remember what it was called.